# Mocking adding items to a list in .NET NMock2

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nmock

I'm using NMock2 (2.1.3641.27570) in my unit tests.

`IList<MyObj> values = _mock.NewMock<IList<MyObj>>();`

That mock I return when my tested object calls the `Values` get property on my mocked object:

`Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(_myKeepMock).GetProperty("Values").Will(Return.Value(values));`

Then I expect `value` which is a `MyObj` to be added to my list `values`:

`Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(values).Method("Add").With(value);`

In order to avoid `unexpected invocation of list'1.Add` upon execution I understand I have to override the `Equals` method in the `MyObj` class:

`public override bool Equals(object obj) { ...}`

and compare by value instead of reference. But it doesn't even get called when executing the test (breakpoint not hit).

What do I need to do in order to pass the test when the item added to the list in the call is equal in value to the one added by the tested object?

I read about custom matchers but not sure if those apply here.

**UPDATE**

Full example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NMock2;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class Data
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public Data(int val) { Val = val; }


}
public class ModData
{
    public int Val { get; set; }


    protected bool Equals(ModData other)
    {
        return this.Val.Equals(other.Val);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Val.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        ModData m = (ModData)obj;

        return m != null && this.Val == m.Val;
    }

}


public interface IAllData
{
    IList<Data> Data { get; set; }
    IList<ModData> ModData { get; set; }
}

public class AllData : IAllData
{
    public IList<Data> Data { get; set; }
    public IList<ModData> ModData { get; set; }


}

public class Calco
{
    private IAllData _allData;

    public Calco(IAllData allData)
    {
        _allData = allData;
    }

    public void Sum()
    {
        _allData.ModData.Add(new ModData { Val = _allData.Data.Sum(d => d.Val) });
    }
}





public class CalcoTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Mockery mockery = new Mockery();
        IList<Data> data = new List<Data>();
        IList<ModData> modData = mockery.NewMock<IList<ModData>>();
        IAllData allData = mockery.NewMock<IAllData>();

        ModData modDatum = new ModData { Val = 4 };

        data.Add(new Data(1));
        data.Add(new Data(10));

        Calco c = new Calco(allData);



        Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(allData).GetProperty("Data").Will(Return.Value(data));
        Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(allData).GetProperty("ModData").Will(Return.Value(modData));
        Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(modData).Method("Add").With(modDatum);

        c.Sum();

        mockery.VerifyAllExpectationsHaveBeenMet();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
NMock2.Internal.ExpectationException : unexpected invocation of list`1.Add(<WRM.Common.RiskCalculation.Tests.ModData>)
Expected:   
  at least 1 time: allData.Data, will return <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WRM.Common.RiskCalculation.Tests.Data]> [called 1 time]
  at least 1 time: allData.ModData, will return <list`1> [called 1 time]
  at least 1 time: list`1.Add(equal to <WRM.Common.RiskCalculation.Tests.ModData>) [called 0 times]
```

Notice how it expects invocation of `list'1.Add(<WRM.Common.RiskCalculation.Tests.ModData>)` 
and then shows it didn't call `list'1.Add(<WRM.Common.RiskCalculation.Tests.ModData>)`

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Matchers ARE the answer: http://nmock.sourceforge.net/advanced.html

```
public class IsMod
{
    public static Matcher Equal(ModData otherMod)
    {
        return new ModMatcher(otherMod);
    }
}

internal class ModMatcher : Matcher
{
    private readonly ModData _mod;

    public ModMatcher(ModData mod)
    {
        _mod = mod;
    }

    public override bool Matches(object o)
    {

        ModData m = (ModData)o;
        return _mod.Val.Equals(m.Val);
    }

    public override void DescribeTo(TextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("Value same ");
        writer.Write(_mod.Val);
    }
}
```

And then

```
Expect.AtLeastOnce.On(modData).Method("Add").With(IsMod.Equal(modDatum));
```

Done!